# GIT: Creating branch from fork repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I fork a repository and set the remote configuration:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/myAccount/someRepo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myAccount/someRepo.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/someAccount/someRepo.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/someAccount/someRepo.git (push)
```

But I want to create branch from:

```
https://github.com/myAccount/someRepo.git
```

If I create that branch locally and then push the branch, will that branch go to `origin` only?

For example:

```
git checkout -b debug

git push -u origin debug
```

Comment: @das-g What I'm trying to figure out is create a branch it will only be created on origin ?

Comment: I've rephrased your question to be (hopefully) more clear. Does it still ask what you want to ask?

Comment: Yes. You have to specify to send upstream if that is what you want `git push --set-upstream origin debug`.

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
git push -u <remote> <branch>
```

This will (a) push branch `<branch>` to remote `<remote>`, and (b) after that, running `git push` while on that branch will always push it to `<remote>`.  I believe that answers your question.